# Log4net deployment 

Tags: 2007, deployment, web-config, logging

We're developing web parts using log4net as the logging framework.  Right now we're leaving the configuration details in the web.config and will be moving the log4net.dll to the GAC manually.

For a small development team (2 devs) and an internal sharepoint installation, is that adequate?  I've read about using WspBuilder, creating a setup project, a globablly scoped solutions, and so on for deployment but We really aren't going to have that much custom code.  Most of our sites will be using out-of-the-box or third-party web parts along with Enterprise features like the Business Data Catalog and Reporting Services.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Enterprise license (and by association, are working for a large company), then you certainly should be doing things the proper way - you owe it to the guy that will come in after you to maintain the environment.

WSPBuilder is really as simple as it gets for packaging things up correctly, doing it the "SharePoint way".  You'll need to drop the log4net dll into a folder named "GAC" in the root of your project, and make the web.config changes via the API.  The terms to search for will be "web config modification" and "feature receiver".

I strongly advise that you do this for this "small" change - it'll get you used to using the tools, and more familiar/confident in how to get the work done.

Comment: This was very helpful.  I'll +1 when I get to 15 rep.